# How do I force Nautilus to log out of a shared drive (samba) so I can log in as a different user?

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, samba

The password isn't stored in my keyring and unmounting the network drive from my desktop doesn't work. It looks like this question has been asked for previous Ubuntu versions but none of the suggestions worked on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of entering `smb://hostname/data` into the Nautilus window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select text input), type `smb://different_user@hostname/data` and it forces a login as different_user.